# Чтение гиперссылок из Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Нужно получить эти ссылки с ячейки

[image]

Что я пробовал:

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

Так возвращает только текст

[image]

Так же пробовал все варианты `valueRenderOption`, изменений не произошло

Comment: А как вы программируете в Google Sheets на python? Там же вроде редактор макросов на Javascript?

Comment: @Глеб,  Через библиотеку google-api-python-client, скрипт работает на отдельном сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел для себя такое решение

```
result = sheet.get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=range_name, includeGridData=True).execute()
for row in result:
    url = row['values'][0]["textFormatRuns"]['format']['link']['uri']
```